# Vue Storefront keeps giving error showing products

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, shopify, vue-storefront

I am using Vue Storefront with Shopify Integration and I keep getting an error in the command line and also the browser. In the browser when ever I click the product or the category I get  broken link

```
**An error occured -Please go back or try again**
```

In the Command Prompt this shows when I navigate to those pages.

> [VSF][error]:  useFacet/useFacet/search Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products')
>
> ```
>   at search (server.js:26226:56)
>   at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
>   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> ```

and

> **[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')**

found in

```
<Pages/Category.vue> at pages/Category.vue
   <Nuxt>
    <DefaultLayout> at layouts/default.vue
       <Root>
```

This is a fresh install of Vue Storefront - why am I having this issue out the box ? How do I fix this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this integration is a community-maintained integration, which means it’s an outsider agency looking after it. We apologize for the bad experience, but right now our in-house maintained integrations are our sole focus.
There’s a chance the agency behind Shopify’s integration will update it to our latest version, but we have no timeline yet for that.

If you're interested, there is a new OS integration in the works here:

https://github.com/TidycodeIT/nuxt3-magento-sdk-storefront

It's still a work in progress, but it will get you started with the latest and greatest Like Nuxt 3 and the new SDK based integration from VSF.